# Not able to mention properties file from maven resources folder in web.xml as context param value

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, quartz-scheduler

I am writing some Quartz jobs. The quartz properties file and quartz jobs xml are saved under src/main/resources/quartz/ folder.

I am providing path to quartz properties file like this :

```
<!-- Quartz schedular context parameters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am getting an Exception : 
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Properties file: 'classpath*:quartz.properties' could not be read. [See nested exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath*:quartz.properties (No such file or directory)]

I tried adding quartz properties file under /WEB-INF/quartz folder and giving path

```
<param-value>classpath*:quartz.properties</param-value>
```

in web xml.

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

UPDATE : 
FOlder structure of exploded war folder :

```
appFolder - WEB-INF
           |_ classes
                   |_ quartz (with properties file in it)
                   |_ com (all class files in it)
           |_ lib
           |_ spring (spring-servlet.xml in it)
           |_ view (jsp files in it)
           |_ web.xml
```

Comment: can you include the files and folder structure in WEB-INF folder within the war in the post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue got resolved. Quartz searches for the properties file named quartz.properties in classpath. I put my properties file and xml files directly in src/main/resources folder.
After deployment these resources are added to classpath.

And the tag in web.xml is like :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
    <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

No need to suffix folder name or provide classpath* keyword in there.

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
classpath:**/quartz.properties
```

Comment: Still getting same error. 
Properties file: 'classpath:**/quartz.properties' could not be read.

Answer (score 0):

Also try changing

```
<param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
```

to

```
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
```

and param value

```
  <param-value>classpath:quartz/quartz.properties</param-value>
```

Comment: try <param-value>classpath:quartz/quartz.properties</param-value>